# getting next results using rvest submit_form

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, rvest, httr

I have the following from a website which I am trying to scrape

```
    <td align="right">
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblCount1">825 records found, </span>
                Page
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCurrent1" type="text" value="1" maxlength="4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCurrent1" style="width:30px;" />
                of
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTotalPage1">83</span>
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnGo1" value="GO" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnGo1" class="inputbtn" />
            </td>
```

I have tried the following code using the rvest package

```
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,`ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCurrent1` = 2)
result <- submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
```

I am not getting the next table in the website returned to me.  How I do use this package to submit a value and get back the resulting HTML?  I've done some poking around and maybe I should be using the `R` packages `httr` and `rcurl` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  The correct code is:

```
pgsession <- html_session("url")
pgform <- html_form(read_html(pgsession))[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform, `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCurrent1` =2)
result <- submit_form(pgsession,filled_form, submit='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnGo1')
case_home <- read_html(result)
```